# How to use $when in an adaptive card template to find out the length of an incoming data payload and drop an input block

Tags: json, botframework, chatbot, templating, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card in the form of a JSON file, which contains an `Input.ChoiceSet`. This is provided with a data payload, which is dynamic and so it is not the same amount of data every time. I want to be able to drop this `Input.ChoiceSet` if it breaks a certain threshold based on the length of the array of data that I'm going to pass to it. Is it possible to write this as an condition inside the `Input.ChoiceSet` using `%when` to carry this out?

This is currently what I have, but it is not working as I would've hoped:

```
{
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "id": "CompactSelectVal1",
      "$when": "${$data.length < 400}",
      "placeholder": "Select a value",
      "choices": [
        {
          "$data": "${data}",
          "title": "${name}",
          "value": "${tag}"
        }
      ],
      "label": "Input"
}
```

Using `.length` here was just a guess here, not based on any documentation. The documentation I have used to find out about `$when` is the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know it's really required extra '$' inside the curly bracket inside condition layout. You can pass separate length parameter into the adaptivecard for verifying the length.

Comment: Removing the '$' inside the curly brackets hasn't made a difference but how would I go about working out the length parameter? data.length doesn't seem to be working for me in this conditional expression

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean here, so pass the length of the data as an element inside the data array and use that in the JSON code to verify the length

Comment: Exactly instead of doing all the activity in adaptive card the length you can pass before moving into it. I will verify is there any option to check length inside adaptive card.

Comment: count method is working for me and you can try out my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "count" property instead of "length" and also remove the extra '$' inside the curly bracket *"${$data.length < 400}"*.

**Try this:**

```
{
  "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
  "id": "CompactSelectVal1",
  "$when": "${count(data) < 400}",
  "placeholder": "Select a value",
  "choices": [
    {
      "$data": "${data}",
      "title": "${name}",
      "value": "${tag}"
    }
  ],
  "label": "Input"
}
```

If the condition is true then the choice button will hide from the adaptive card.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also found that using "${count(data) < 400}" also works as well.

Comment: Do you also know if its possible to do a fallback case when using $when?

Comment: I don't remember any fallback option but chances are very less. Better you can validate all the condition before passing into adaptive card that will reduce the risk.